# ImportError: libqgis_core.so.2.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: pyqgis, installation

I installed qgis in debian linux and I want to run a standalone app in python. So I import qgis.core and qgis.gui in this app.
But it gives me an error:

```
  ImportError: libqgis_core.so.2.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I installed the last version using:

```
deb     http://qgis.org/debian jessie main
deb-src http://qgis.org/debian jessie main
```

My PYTHONPATH is defined to: /usr/share/qgis/python/plugins. And I search libqgis_core and I found the libqgis._core2.8.0. So why the app is searching the 2.9.0 version?

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly set LD_LYBRARY_PATH  which is explained here: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#running-custom-applications

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the solution. I need to uninstall all and install again, inclusive python-qgis. Now the it is fixed. Thank you.